# is there any alternative in python to replace the variable in runtime like in unix shell script {!variableName}

Tags: python

In unix shell script: 
if I call 
`function_name "${!variable}"` -> variable will replaced during the execution/runtime

is there something alternative exists in python? there are some other logic involved prior creating the `variable`. But I'm interested in `{!variable}` alternative.

Comment: You have an XY problem, in that you are trying to store variable names as data in the first place. You probably want to use a `dict`, not a loose assortment of individual variables, to hold your data.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the `eval` function:

```
a = "there"
b = "a"
eval(b)
```

Yielding the output:

```
'there'
```

Of course, the `eval` function, while being a bit more verbose than the **bash** indirect variable reference, is also much more versatile, as you can have the indirectly referenced variable (`b` in this case), contain any python expression.

Comment: you are giving a bash answer, he asks for a python alternative.

Comment: @Chris That doesn't look like bash syntax

Comment: @ChrisMaes This answer is not bash. I just tried it in python3 and it works.

Comment: my bad. Your answer is correct. This still is a duplicate question though which should be flagged as such.

Comment: thanks i didn't know, there is an eval in python. I think this is my answer. will close this.

Comment: `eval` is also far more *dangerous*, because it *doesn't* just perform indirect parameter expansion.

Comment: So @chepner what's your take then?

Comment: My take is that the OP should be using a `dict`, not a loose collection of related variables.

Comment: all the user wants to do is call a function dynamically - meaning determined at run time. eval is not the right tool. It is like using a jack hammer with a needle.

Comment: [**Do not ever use `eval` (or `exec`) on data that could possibly come from outside the program in any form. It is a critical security risk. You allow the author of the data to run arbitrary code on your computer.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice)

Answer (score 0):

In python functions are 1st class objects. Which means you can pass them around just like any variable.

```
def print_this():
    print('this')

def print_that():
    print('that')

p1 = print_this
p2 = print_that

p1()
p2()
```

So you don't need to use `eval`.

Comment: You are making some assumption on why th OP needs to access a variable by name. You may be right, but the strict answer to his question is using `eval`. I also do not think that OP is trying to place the name of a function in a variable, but simply pass the content of name of a variable to a function (I'm no **bash** expert).

Comment: eval can be dangerous and should be used only as a last resort. I would not suggest that as a first step.

Comment: I checked the **bash** syntax for functions, and I think you misinterpreted the OP's question. What OP wanted was not to called a function named in a variable, but call a known function, and pass to it the content of a variable who's name was in another variable. The answer you provided is a good answer to a different question.

Comment: If that is the case, then @chepner answer to use a `dict` is the correct one. Cannot recommend `eval`.